# Is it still "you are" in this specific situation?

Tags: emphasis

I know one says "you are" regardless if "you" is used as plural or singular, but what happens if you use it in "you, my friend, (...). Is it changed into "you, my friend, is..." or "you, my friend, are..." Please help.

Comment: It’s always *are*.

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly quick response Dan! Appreciate it, I'm writing a book at this very moment.

Comment: You always use plural you. So, you are is correct.

Comment: It is never _your are_, however (unless you’re talking about the rather obscure old word _are_ meaning ‘grace’ or the deprecated SI unit that forms the basis of _hectare_).

Answer (score 1):

As you have said, it is *you are* regardless whether *you* is used as singular or plural. In the case given, "*you, my friend, (...)*" it is still *are*, as in, "*you, my friend, are*".

The sentence structure around the insertion of *my friend*, delineated by commas, remains the same whether the insertion exists or not. The extra noun phrase, added for emphasis, does not alter the construction of the clause in which it has been inserted.

Comment: The "extra clause" isn't even a clause.  It's just a noun phrase used as an *address*.  It's only function is to identify the intended audience of the associated clause.